# Filtering infinite list causing memory overload in Haskell/GHCI

Tags: haskell, infinite

I'm trying to write some Haskell code that will spit out a bunch of valid sudoku puzzles. Heres the code I have so far:

```
import Data.List (nub, permutations, transpose)

-- Recursively build list of possible permutations of a certain length, allowing duplicates
genPermutations list length
    | length <= 0 = [[]]
    | length == 1 = [[a] | a <- list]
    | otherwise = [[a]++b | a <- list, b <- genPermutations list $ length - 1]

-- Generate as flat list of length 9, then format
squares = [[take 3 a,take 3 $ drop 3 a, drop 6 a] | a <- permutations [1..9]]
sudokus = [[take 3 a,take 3 $ drop 3 a, drop 6 a] | a <- genPermutations squares 9]

-- Takes a sudoku as a 4d array, return True/Flase based on rules of sudoku
-- Does not check for duplicates within a square because generated sudokus shouldn't have any
checkSudukoValid x = (foldr (==) True $ map screenLineForDuplicates x) && (foldr (==) True $ map screenLineForDuplicates $ transposeSudoku x)
    where transposeSudoku x = transpose(map (\x -> map transpose x )  x)
          screenLineForDuplicates [[],[],[]] = True
          screenLineForDuplicates [a:al,b:bl,c:cl] = check && screenLineForDuplicates [al,bl,cl]
              where check = (length line)  == (length $ nub line)
                    line = concat [a,b,c]


-- Known good sudoku for testing
knownGood = [[[[9,8,3],[6,1,4],[5,2,7]],[[6,5,7],[2,8,9],[4,3,1]],[[2,4,1],[5,7,3],[9,6,8]]],[[[8,6,5],[4,3,1],[7,9,2]],[[3,2,4],[7,9,8],[1,6,5]],[[7,1,9],[6,5,2],[3,8,4]]],[[[2,7,8],[3,5,9],[1,4,6]],[[5,1,3],[8,4,6],[9,7,2]],[[4,9,6],[1,2,7],[8,3,5]]]]
```

The important part of this code is that it generates a list of possibly valid sudoku puzzles & a method to that if a single puzzle is valid. From my understanding, I should be able to just filter said list to get out some valid sudokus:
`head $ filter checkSudukoValid sudokus`

When I run this, GHCI kills my process, which seems to be because of memory issues. What I don't understand is why I am running into memory problems. Shouldn't haskell be lazily filtering through the items in the list one at a time? Why would this take up significantly more memory than, say `filter checkSudukoValid $ take 5 sudokus`

What am I missing about how Haskell handles infinite list that would cause this? Is there a standard solution to making this more lazy that would cause me not to run into memory issues?

Comment: Can you show us the error you are receiving?

Comment: It could be that `checkSudokuValid` is what is taking a very long time.  Do some experimentation with `head $ filter checkSudokusValid $ take n sudokus` where you increase `n` until you find where it runs out of memory.  See if you can find an element in `sudokus` that causes `checkSudokusValid` to run out of memory.

Comment: @JustinWood No error, GHCI just exits and I get "Killed". Googling has led me toward memory as the cause of that, but its mostly an educated guess.

Comment: Still tracing it, but it seems like @bheklilr was onto something

Comment: `take 1 $ drop 1599999 sudokus` is causing a similar crash, so it seems like my list itself is causing the issue, and not my filter. I guess my permutations function is FUBAR

Comment: I doubt this has much to do with it, but `foldr (==) True` is a very strange thing to write. Perhaps you meant `and`, which is `foldr (&&) True`, or perhaps you meant `(\xs -> and $ zipWith (==) xs (tail xs))`.

Comment: @dfeuer Correct me if I'm wrong, but since my list input to foldr should only be booleans, (==) and (&&) would be equivalent, no? I guess (&&) might be more efficient.

Comment: @MrGlass, no, folding `(==)` will not do what you think it will do. For example `foldr (==) True [a,b] = a == (b == True) = (a && b) || (not a && not b) = a == b`, but then `foldr (==) True [a,b,c] = a == (b == c) = (a && b==c) || (not a && b/=c)` and you have something very strange already. It would probably actually be rather interesting to try to come up with a simple explanation of what `foldr (==) True` actually does, but it's certainly not something you're likely to see in the wild.

Comment: This looks like a 3D sudoku variant. Is that right?

Comment: @dfeuer Just a regular sudoku, but because im just structuring it with lists of lists it might look 3d.

Comment: @dfeuer `(False ==)` is `not` and `(True ==)` is `id`. So `foldr (==) True` tells whether there are an even or odd number of `False`s in the argument list.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is definitely in the generation code, and not the checking code (although there are a lot of things that should be changed in both). Specifically, your `genPermutations` implementation seems to use more and more RAM as it goes. I haven't figured out why that is yet, but if you use

```
genPermutations xs n = map (take n) $ permutations xs
```

the memory use goes down to constant. This will not, however, actually make your program work, for at least two reasons.

One reason is that your validity test is wrong; as I mentioned before, folding `(==)` does not do what you think. What you meant to do was

```
checkSudukoValid x = (all screenLineForDuplicates x) && (all 
screenLineForDuplicates $ transposeSudoku x)
    where transposeSudoku x = transpose(map (\x -> map transpose x )  x)
          screenLineForDuplicates [[],[],[]] = True
          screenLineForDuplicates [a:al,b:bl,c:cl] = check && screenLineForDuplicates [al,bl,cl]
              where check = (length line)  == (length $ nub line)
                    line = concat [a,b,c]
```

This is terribly inefficient, but I think it's probably correct.

The other reason is more serious: using either my version of `genPermutations` or yours, you will get a huge number of invalid puzzles before you hit the first valid one. I wasn't patient enough to wait for it.

Comment: That code for genPermutations generates a lot of duplicates. Also, permutations doesn't allow multiple entries of the same value in the permutation (EG, for permutations of the list [1..3] I want [1,1,1,1,1] to be included

Comment: @MrGlass, ah, that's a point, and I can fix it, but your problem will remain.

Comment: I always knew time would be an issue. Thats why i was trying to get 1 just to prove my concept, and was shocked to get the killed process. I'm happy to leave my machine churning through this for a few days for a result.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
genPermutations list length = sequence (replicate length list)
```

Comment: That seems to run a bit faster but still dies.